# How to make a function repeat/loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have a function here for centering an element within it's parent.
Check out the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kE9xW/1/

right now it's only applying the centering to the first element, how do i make the function loop itself so it centers every `#element` on the page. the demo is self explanatory, thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/kE9xW/3/ It works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do.

1. As already suggested, id's must be unique, so change the id="..." to class="...". You will also need to change your css to be based on the class not the id (change #element' to '.element')

   ```
   <div class="container">
      <p> ... </p>
       <div class="element">
           &nbsp;
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Use `each` in your method to loop over all elements selected by the selector `$('.element')`.

   ```
   element.each(function(){
     // work here in $(this) for the current element
   });
   ```
3. You forgot to take the top of the parent div into account, which made all elements overlap each other. So your yPas becomes:

   ```
   var yPos = $(this).parent().position().top + 
           parseInt($(this).parent().css('height'))/2 -
           parseInt($(this).css('height'))/2 - yPosFromCenter;
   ```

Check the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H99DT/

Answer (score 3):

First, the easiest but most important part: change your IDs to classes. IDs must be unique per page so [jQuery's ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector) and JavaScript's `document.getElementById()` function are only going to give you the first matching element:

> Each `id` value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.

Change

```
<div id="container">
    ...
    <div id="element">
```

to

```
<div class="container">
    ...
    <div class="element">
```

and change

```
$('#element')
```

to

```
$('.element')
```

Next, the more difficult part: you are currently issuing one `centerDiv()` call to your elements with coordinates from center of `0, 0`. That's going to take all your `.element`s and position them at the exact same spot.

<del>If that's not what you intend, you're going to have to loop through them using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) and decide the `xPosFromCenter` and `yPosFromCenter` in each iteration. It's not clear to me yet how your function works so you may have to explore on your own and see what you can come up with.</del>

Scratch that, see [Jamiec's working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829135/jquery-how-to-make-a-function-repeat-loop/4829172#4829172) for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change **Id** to **class** in you divs, then make container's position relative with css, and I'll suggest make jQuery plugin from your function. See results http://jsfiddle.net/kE9xW/1/